# Heroku and gems only for production environment

Tags: git, heroku, production-environment, gemfile

I have an application that must be run in three different environments, called dev, beta and prod.

I created three different applications on heroku, so all the environments can be run at the same time, and I deploy the code from the right git repo to the right application when I need to. I think that it is a completely normal situation :-)

I have a branch on git for dev purpose, when I need, I branch a beta version to deploy on beta, when it is ready, I deploy on prod and merge back to the trunk, following this [branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)

I would like to add the New Relic monitoring system, as an Heroku add-on, only to one of the application, the production one.
To install New Relic, you have to include a gem in the Gemfile, so I need to include the gem only for production Gemfile.

Given that the current stack on Heroku does not support the groups in the Gemfile, how can I achieve this goal? Should I have to manage by hand each gem file before bringing to production?

EDIT

To better clafify what I tried, maybe I am missing something obvious:

I added

```
group :production do
   gem 'newrelic_rpm'
end
```

to Gemfile.
My dev environment has RACK_ENV and RAILS_ENV set to development, when I push to heroku the application is deployed with the newrelic gem.

Answer (score 0):

> Given that the current stack on Heroku does not support the groups in
>   the Gemfile

I don't believe this to be an accurate statement.

```
group :production do
  gem 'some_production_gem'
end
```

Will only install `some_production_gem` in the `production` environment. Use `RACK_ENV` and `RAILS_ENV` env vars for your separate applications to manage that. I believe `group :staging` would work the same, if you specified `RAILS_ENV: staging` in your Heroku environment variables.

- [Managing Multiple Environments for an App](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments#managing-staging-and-production-configurations) ( specifically **Managing staging and production configurations** )
- [Configuration and Config Vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but as I found on https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler#specifying-gems-and-groups "Please note - for the time being, the Cedar stack does not support BUNDLE_WITHOUT." So, also if I specify the gem with the group statement, this doesn't matter at all, heroku will bring the gem also in my dev or staging or whatever environment. I tried with New Relic, and immediately my app on development environment was carefully monitored :-). But maybe I miss something...

Answer (score 0):

From https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler#specifying-gems-and-groups ...

If you would like to use `BUNDLE_WITHOUT` on cedar, you need to enable the `user-env-compile` feature flag. After enabling the feature flag, you can exclude certain groups from being installed by using the `BUNDLE_WITHOUT` config var:

```
$ heroku config:set BUNDLE_WITHOUT="development:test"
```

From https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/labs-user-env-compile#enabling ...

To enable the feature:

```
$ heroku labs:enable user-env-compile -a myapp
```

**A note from Heroku's security:**

The use of the `user-env-compile` feature is **discouraged** because *it writes your config vars into the slug in plaintext*.